# marker google map real time

Tags: javascript, php, html, real-time

I would like to know how I could load the coordinates (longitude and latitude) of my database in real time without updating the page even if there will be changes in the database.

I used setInterval (function ()) to reload data but still get the same coordinates.

```html
<?php
                 try
{
  $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fma120;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
        
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT latitude,longitude FROM gps_data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ');
$donnees = $reponse->fetch() ;
 
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat:<?php echo $donnees['latitude'] ;?> , lng: <?php echo $donnees['longitude'] ;?>
          };
 
 
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
                    
setInterval(function(){ initMap() }, 3000);
 
 
    </script>
    <script
 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyADJopukImlmQs73l4o3xdddlcg_OBj1vaqB8&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I explain:

my script loads the map (the last id = 1) .. after I add another column in the database (with id = 2), I would like the script to load the last column (id = 2) without updating the page

Please help me

Comment: I don't see setInterval in your code..

Comment: oops I copied the old code : setInterval(function(){ initMap() }, 3000);

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the setInterval code here, you're not using different parameters, you're just reloading the same map every 3 seconds.   Calling a function in javascript will not affect any PHP code (unless it actually refreshes the page).  It seems like you need to research AJAX requests and possibly use JSON to pass data from your PHP to your Javascript.

Comment: thank you for your reply ,
how can I load the  new data from my database with AJaX ?

Comment: I think you need to research that yourself.  That's pretty broad.